# Is there a way to enforce the interface definition in ngrx/store models (angular 2)?

Tags: angular, ngrx

In different blogposts and in the example linked by the official ngnx/store documentation, i found the following approach as the "standard" way to operate. I will post my code related to adding a user to the store after login.

So first I created an Appstore interface, representing all the objects handled by our application:

```
export interface AppStore {
 user: Observable<User>;
};
```

This is the User model:

```
export interface User {
  id: number;
  username: string;
  email: string;
};
```

Then I created a reducer for the user (where the payload contains user id, email and username)

```
export const user: ActionReducer<User> = (state: User, action: Action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_USER:
      return action.payload;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Finally, I select the 'user' object from the store in this way:

```
  user : User;

  constructor(private store: Store<AppStore>) {

        this.user = <Observable<User>>this.store.select('user');
  }
```

However, if I change the reducer to the following code, the meaningless property gets into the final object even if in my opinion the User interface should avoid this to happen.

```
export const user: ActionReducer<User> = (state: User, action: Action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_USER:
      return Object.assign({},action.payload, meaninglessProperty = 'abcd');
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

So, my question is: is the AppStore interface just a way to visualize / understand our app’s overall store structure or does ngrx store actually check that the properties in Appstore respect their own interface contract?

- In case it does, what i am missing?
- In case it doesn't, can i change something in order to ensure that the interface definition will be enforced at runtime?

I ask this because I have more complex scenarios in which checking the interfaces would make the code "safer" and it would reduce a lot the risk of making mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You question is not really related to ngrx, but concerns more the Typescript Type-system in regards to `Object.assign`, which does unfortunately not cover your case - you can also have a look at this thread on github for additional details on the issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10532